# How to implement couchbase lite on android?

Tags: android, couchbase, implementation, couchbase-lite

what I am trying to do is implement couchbase lite. I am using the official documentation but do not quite get it

I used

```
implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.0.0'
```

but for some reason, on the databasemanager class, gives me an error

```
// tag::initCouchbaseLite[]
public void initCouchbaseLite(Context context) {
    CouchbaseLite.init(context);
}
// end::initCouchbaseLite[]
```

the "CouchBaseLite" is highlighted and says cannot resolve reference. I cannot seem to get it to work

Any help or suggestion on what to look for would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use version `2.8.0` this should work. Also support for down to API-21 was deprecated in release 2.6 So if your app has minimum API version > 21 then its fine otherwise you might have to change it later.

```
implementation "com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.8.0"
```